# Finding IP addresses using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the results of the TSHARK capture

Here is the line I am filtering on:

```
Internet Protocol, Src: 10.10.52.250 (10.10.52.250), Dst: 224.0.0.2 (224.0.0.2)
```

I am trying to extract the Src and Dst,

Here is my code to do that:

```
str(re.search("Src:\s[0-9\.]{7-15}", a, re.I|re.M).group())[5:]
str(re.search("Dst:\s[0-9\.]{7-15}", a, re.I|re.M).group())[5:]
```

I keep getting no match when I run this, but when I use the exact length of the IP address in the regular expression it works. ie

```
str(re.search("Src:\s[0-9\.]{9}", a, re.I|re.M).group())[5:]
```

Works just fine. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you really want to match "..1234567890123" as a valid IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for match in re.finditer(r"\((\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?))\b\)", subject):
```

This should match any IPV4 IP address. Actual IPs are captured into group 1.

While your regex may work, it is dangerous because 999.999.999.999 is **not** a valid but it will match.

Comment: I am writing a script that will have to parse traffic during a hacking competition, I need to be able to catch any packets crafted in scapy.They may not be valid IP addresses.

Comment: But it's physically impossible to store 999.999.999.999 in an IP packet's address field, which is a 32-bit number. A single 8-bit octet from that field can never represent a decimal number > 255.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [Python regex howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#repeating-things), shouldn't that be `{7,15}`?

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it right away. I'm not quite sure how that worked the last time I tested the script at work.

Answer (score 2):

Not very nice:

```
text = 'fasga@fas#2*^127.0.0.1tfgws5151'

pattern = r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"
pattern_re = re.compile(pattern)
ip_address = pattern_re.findall(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{7,15}`:

```
str(re.search("Src:\s[0-9\.]{7,15}", a, re.I|re.M).group())[5:]
str(re.search("Dst:\s[0-9\.]{7,15}", a, re.I|re.M).group())[5:]
```

Also, you should check that a group exists first (or put a `try`/`except` around it):

```
groupFound = re.search("Src:\s*[\d\.]{7,15}", a, re.I | re.M)
if groupFound:
    str(groupFound.group())[5:]

# or:

try:
    str(re.search("Src:\s*[\d\.]{7,15}", a, re.I | re.M).group())[5:]
except AttributeError:
    # handle it
```